# Multiple Foreign Keys in One Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two models called 'Event' & 'Currency'.

In the Event model the respective fields are id, prize_pool, title, name, currency_id, prize_pool_currency_id and in Currency model their fields are id, currency.

Event.rb

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :prize_pool,:title,:name,:currency_id,:prize_pool_currency_id
belongs_to :buy_currency, :class_name => 'Currency', :foreign_key => 'currency_id'
  belongs_to :prize_pool_currency, :class_name => 'Currency', :foreign_key => 'prize_pool_currency_id'
end
```

Currency.rb

```
class Currency < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :currency
  has_one :event
  has_one :event_player
end
```

In the controller when we access it I'm given this error:

"Association named 'currency' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?"

How to access or associate to one another so that all foreign key access easily?

Comment: How are you accessing the association? Please post your controller

Comment: @poker_result=Event.includes(:currency)

Comment: You don't have a association defined on event called `currency`. do you mean to use `buy_currency`?

Comment: Association already defined in Event model. 'buy_currency' is just a dummy name here accessing with class_name=> Currency

Answer (score 0):

You can access association using the name you gave for the association(not the class name). In your case, it would be `buy_currency` or `prize_pool_currency`

```
@poker_result = Event.includes(:buy_currency)
```